# visual studio workflow

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2012

So I tried to follow the tutorial on the following site:
http://www.bing.com/videos/watch/video/developing-sharepoint-2013-workflows-with-visual-studio-demo/10t0er5gh?from=email&src=v5%253ashare%253aemail

the problem is when I try to make an httpSend request, vs crashes, and I know for sure that the link I am using works. Can anyone think of a reason why this would be happening? I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure this out!

What I'm using : VS2012, sp2013

Comment: Can you post your code? Did you try to debug?